# mysql union problems with subtraction

Tags: mysql, sum, union, subtraction

**for example:** I have 4 tables:
table 1 : item

```
item_id    name   quantity
==========================
1          a      10
2          b      15
```

table 2 : additional

```
add_id     name   quantity  item_id
===================================
1          c      5         1
```

table 3 : item_out (this will subtract item quantity)

```
item_id    quantity
==========================
1          10
2          5
```

table 4 : additional_out (this will subtract additional quantity)

```
additional_id     quantity
==========================
1                 5
```

My question is: what mysql-query should I give in order to get these result?

```
item_ id   quantity   additional_id    additinal_quantity
=================================================
1          5          1                0
2          15
```

because I use mysql query code like:

```
SELECT item_id, SUM(quantity - IFNULL(number,0)), additional_id, SUM(additional_quantity - IFNULL(additional_number,0))
FROM(
   SELECT a.item_id, a.quantity, b.additional_id, b.quantity AS additional_quantity, NULL AS number, NULL AS additional_number
   FROM table_1 a JOIN table_2 b ON some condition
   UNION
   SELECT NULL AS item_id , NULL AS quantity,... a.quantity AS number, b.quantity AS additional_number
   FROM table_3 a JOIN table_4 b ON condition
)AS T
```

and it ends with only 1 row because of SUM in the first selection.

Comment: You're just missing `GROUP BY item_id`, aren't you?

Comment: How are all these tables related to each other? Why do you have `NULL AS item_id` in the second query of the union? Do those quantities get subtracted from all items?

Comment: I suspect you should be using `LEFT JOIN` and `CROSS JOIN`, not `UNION`.

Comment: @Barmar amazingly it works with adding GROUP BY! thanks man!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT item_ id, 
  (item.quantity - IFNULL(item_out.quantity,0)) AS quantity, 
  additional_id, 
  (IFNULL(a.quantity,0) - IFNULL(ao.quantity,0)) AS additional_quantity
FROM item
LEFT JOIN item_out
ON item.item_id = item_out.item_id
LEFT JOIN additional a
ON item.item_id = a.item_id
LEFT JOIN additional_out ao
ON a.addid = ao.additional_id
```